# swagger uses JWT for verification has been 401

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I referred to some posts, and then I verified on swagger. I found that no matter what, I always showed that I have no permission. Is my configuration wrong?

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(x =>
            {
                x.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiInfo { Title = "ShareThoughtAPI", Version = "v1 " });
                var security = new OpenApiSecurityRequirement();
                x.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                {
                    Description = "JWT Authorization header using the bearer scheme",
                    Name = "Authorization",
                    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                    Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey
                });
                x.AddSecurityRequirement(security);
            });
```

Comment: One solution I found it's on this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75798828/22146505

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I write a simple demo about swagger uses JWT for verification , You can check and find where is the difference.

**appsettings.json**

```
  "Jwt": {
    "Issuer": "testUser",
    "Audience": "user",
    "Key": "this is my custom Secret key for authnetication"
  }
```

**Startup.cs**

Enable the JWT authentication scheme and swagger authorization configuration when the configuration starts, the entire code is as follows:

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            //services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);
            services.AddAuthentication(opt => {
                opt.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                opt.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
             .AddJwtBearer(options =>
             {
                 options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                 {
                     ValidateIssuer = true,
                     ValidateAudience = true,
                     ValidateLifetime = true,
                     ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                     ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                     ValidAudience = Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
                     IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
                 };
             });

             services.AddControllers();

            services.AddSwaggerGen(config =>
            {
                config.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                {
                    Description =
        "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. \r\n\r\n Enter 'Bearer' [space] and then your token in the text input below.\r\n\r\nExample: \"Bearer 12345abcdef\"",
                    Name = "Authorization",
                    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                    Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
                    Scheme = "Bearer",
                    BearerFormat = "JWT"
                });


                config.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement()
                {
                    {
                        new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                        {
                            Reference = new OpenApiReference
                            {
                                Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                                Id = "Bearer"
                            },
                            Scheme = "oauth2",
                            Name = "Bearer",
                            In = ParameterLocation.Header,

                        },
                        new List<string>()
                    }
                });


                var titleBase = "Test API";
                var description = "This is a Web API for Test operations";
                var TermsOfService = new Uri("https://xxxxxx");
                var License = new OpenApiLicense()
                {
                    Name = "MIT"
                };
                var Contact = new OpenApiContact()
                {
                    Name = "Test",
                    Email = "Test@hotmail.com",
                    Url = new Uri("https://xxxxxx")
                };

                config.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
                {
                    Version = "v1",
                    Title = titleBase + " v1",
                    Description = description,
                    TermsOfService = TermsOfService,
                    License = License,
                    Contact = Contact
                });

                config.SwaggerDoc("v2", new OpenApiInfo
                {
                    Version = "v2",
                    Title = titleBase + " v2",
                    Description = description,
                    TermsOfService = TermsOfService,
                    License = License,
                    Contact = Contact
                });

                var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
                var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
                config.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(config =>
            {
                config.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Test v1");
                //config.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v2/swagger.json", "Test v2");
            });
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
```

**Model**

```
public class Usuario
    {
        public string NomeUsuario { get; set; }
        public string Senha { get; set; }
    }
```

**Controller**

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class SegurancaController : Controller
    {
        private IConfiguration _config;
        public SegurancaController(IConfiguration Configuration)
        {
            _config = Configuration;
        }
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("login")]
        public IActionResult Login([FromBody] Usuario loginDetalhes)
        {
            bool resultado = ValidarUsuario(loginDetalhes);
            if (resultado)
            {
                var tokenString = GerarTokenJWT();
                return Ok(new { token = tokenString });
            }
            else
            {
                return Unauthorized();
            }
        }

     
        private string GerarTokenJWT()
        {
            var issuer = _config["Jwt:Issuer"];
            var audience = _config["Jwt:Audience"];
            var expiry = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(120);
            var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config["Jwt:Key"]));
            var credentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(issuer: issuer, audience: audience,
expires: expiry, signingCredentials: credentials);
            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var stringToken = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
            return stringToken;
        }
        private bool ValidarUsuario(Usuario loginDetalhes)
        {
            if (loginDetalhes.NomeUsuario == "TestName" && loginDetalhes.Senha == "TestPwd")
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Test APi**

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
        [Route("list_data")]
        [HttpGet]
        [Authorize]
        public Object Data()
        {
            
            return "OK";
        }
    }
```

[image]